How to change check mark in Checkbox on mouse click
I want to know how to change check mark base on mouse button click (left mouse click = ✅ mark / right mouse click =  X mark) on check box.
I can do normal tick mark on check box. but I want to know to put X mark & how to detect check box ✅  or X checked.
I Found Solution
Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.MouseUp

    Select Case e.Button
        Case MouseButtons.Left
            CType(sender, CheckBox).CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        Case MouseButtons.Right
            CType(sender, CheckBox).CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            booErrorFound = True
    End Select
end sub


Private Sub CheckBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.Paint

    Dim pPoint As New Point(e.ClipRectangle.Left, e.ClipRectangle.Top)

    Select Case CheckBox1.CheckState
        Case CheckState.Checked
            CheckBoxPaintLeftMouse(e, New Rectangle(pPoint, New Size(22, 22)))
        Case CheckState.Indeterminate
            CheckBoxPaintRightMouse(e, New Rectangle(pPoint, New Size(22, 22)))
    End Select

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkSlateBlue, New Rectangle(pPoint, New Size(22, 22)))    
End Sub




Private Sub CheckBoxPaintLeftMouse(pePaintEvent As PaintEventArgs,
                                   rRectangle As Rectangle)

        Using fFont As New Font("Wingdings", 15.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
            pePaintEvent.Graphics.DrawString("ü", fFont, Brushes.DarkOrange, rRectangle)
        End Using


End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxPaintRightMouse(pePaintEvent As PaintEventArgs,
                                    rRectangle As Rectangle)
    
        Using fFont As New Font("Wingdings", 15.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
            pePaintEvent.Graphics.DrawString("û", fFont, Brushes.DarkGreen, rRectangle)
        End Using

End Sub


Just a language tag is not sufficient and, in actual fact, fairly irrelevant if you establish that it's .NET. What matters more is the technology. WPF? Windows Forms? ASP.NET MVC? Something else?

Also, how to display something other than a tick in a check box and how set the state of a check box on a right click are two different things and so require two different questions. Just like all questions, both would then require you to show what efforts you've made on your own behalf, because SO is not a place where you just tell us what you want and sit back while we do it for you. If you haven't tried then you haven't failed, so it's too soon to ask a question. If you don't know, the next step is research, not asking us to do it.
